# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm sorry i'm quite new to MySQL and java in general. I've tried to research solutions on other people getting this exception, but I haven't found any solutions specific to my problem.

If I manually insert a tuple, it works completely fine. But when I iterate through a text file and extract the associated data, then insert a tuple into MySQL via java, I get an exception claiming that a 'duplicate entry' exists, however that entry exists only once in my text file.

this is an example of inserting two different tuples:

```
insert into person (last_name, first_name, number, alias_value, has_alias) values ('Gleißner', 'A.', '0', 'g/AGleissner', 'YES');
insert into person (last_name, first_name, number, alias_value, has_alias) values ('Gleißner', 'Andreas', '0', '85/9125', 'NO');
```

where last_name, first_name, and number represent a primary key.

here is are snippets of my code:

```
    Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, 
    Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
```

while a line in the text file is not null:

```
String values = "" + "'" + lastName + "', '" + firstName + "', '" + Integer.toString(number) + "', '" + alias_value + "', '" + alias + "'"; 
String sq1 = "insert into person"
                            + " (last_name, first_name, number, alias_value, has_alias)"
                            + " values (" + values + ")";

myStmt.execute(sq1);
```

here is the Exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'Gleißner-A.-0' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:934)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:839)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:739)
    at mySQLInsert.InsertPerson.main(InsertPerson.java:111)
```

Edit:

Added code to show how data is loaded:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("author_ID.txt")); String person = "";
    while((person=br.readLine()) != null && person.length()!=0) 
    { //here I parse "person", and stored it into local variables within the while loop, then inserted the tuple using PreparedStatement}
```

Temporary (Dirty) Solution:
I changed my Statement into a PreparedStatement and included a ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE so that if Exception occurs, update the tuple with the same values:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO person"
                 + " (last_name, first_name, number, alias)(?,?,?,?)"
                 + " VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
                 + " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"
                 + " last_name=(?), first_name=(?), number=(?)" 
PreparedStatement myStmt = myConn.prepareStatement(query);
```

I think that because the SQL injection is dynamic, the insert command is executing an insert of a set of multiple values more than once. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: How do you iterate over your file? My guess is that your aren't calling .next(), and your lastName/firstName stays the same. Please post more code to confirm that.

Comment: either it is already in your db or you try to insert it twice, there is no trick here. Show us how you read your file and load your entries

Comment: Hi @AlexeySoshin, you're correct, I didn't use an iterator to read my file. this is how I read and loaded my entries:
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("author_ID.txt"));
        String person = "";
        while((person=br.readLine()) != null && person.length()!=0) {
        //here I parse "person", and stored it into local variables within the while loop, then inserted the tuple
        }
I made sure to delete all tuples in my table before inserting any tuples from the text file. I also double checked my text file of any twin tuples

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code where you are looping through the text file and performing the inserts. Don't bury important details in the comments where people might miss them. Also, be aware that by using *dynamic SQL* your code is vulnerable to *SQL injection* and will fail, for example, if `last_name` is "O'Connor". You should use a `PreparedStatement` and a *parameterized query* to avoid such problems.

Comment: Your temporary dirty solution is much less dirty than your original one. Of course a prepared statement should be used.